# How to add UITableview in iPhone app using PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, cordova

Am very new to use PhoneGap to develop iPhone app. I have searched in Google to add UITableView in iPhone app by using PhoneGap framwork. I have `downloaded and installed PhoneGap`. I want to make a `simple iPhone app using UITableView in PhoneGap iPhone apps`. I have referred the below link to develop a simple iphone app via PhoneGap,

> http://taitems.github.com/iOS-Inspired-jQuery-Mobile-Theme/

I have coded for `tableview and having in HTML format`. I don't know how to use and show the tableview in iPhone app using PhoneGap. Could you please help me to use UITableView in iPhone app using PhoneGap? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the "Getting Started" guide at PhoneGap.com?  There are detailed instructions how to setup your PhoneGap iOS application: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

You don't need to use a uitableview using objective c.  You just need to create your HTML interface (divs or tables, etc...).  Phonegap leverages a web view to render your HTML as the mobile application interface.  No objective c coding is necessary.